# Is order of exception handling important?

Tags: c++, exception, types

For example I want to catch exceptions of more than one class of the exception hierarchy of exception classes, do I need to worry about which order they are?

I heard that the order is unimportant because exception handing is built into C++, but I am not 100% sure.

Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of `catch` clauses matters.

`catch` clauses are matched in the order in which they appear, programs that use exceptions from an inheritance hierarchy must order their `catch` clauses so that handlers for a derived type occur before a `catch` for its base type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. First should be caught derived exceptions and least - base.